# Unexpected behavior with -h flag passed to du

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, du

As long as I've been living in *nix world I've lived under the assumption that when a command accepted a `-h` flag the only thing I was changing was effectively formatting of a print statement. I don't usually re-examine this, but have definitely found this to be the case in general.

Today I had a very strange experience when measuring the size of a directory that I was actively writing to.

```
>>> du -s
15565160    .
>>> du -sh
7.4G    .
```

At first I thought that I was just catching the directory in a strange place, but I found that both values were quite persistent, returning only slightly increased/decreased values as I kept writing to the directory. My first assumption was that it was some strange intermediary state, but in that case I would have expected wild swings in the result of `du -s` that I did not observe.

What's going on here? What is the `155...` number? It doesn't seem like it's bytes. There seems to be a pretty consistent ratio between the two of about 450. That is, if I multiple the result of `du -s` by 450 I get pretty close to the number of bytes implied by `du -sh`.

The bigger question is if I've been wrong all along. Why is adding the `-h` flag in this context doing anything other than changing the print format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you're correct. the `-h` flag (when not used to print help text) is used to tell various applications to **convert** the output to "human readable format." This is important... we'll come back to it. For `du` in particular the `-s` flag gives a summary of its normal "per-directory" output. Basically, it adds it all together.

`du` defaults to returning the number of logical blocks a directory and its contents occupy on the storage media. The count of blocks occupied is useful for many disk utilities and scripting... but it's not very "human readable." The -h flag converts the block count back into a number of bytes, then rounds to the nearest factor of 1024 (and a few other shenanigans... we end up with gigabytes and one digit past the decimal in your case).

Given what you've said, I'm willing to bet your system is configured for a 512-byte block size because:

[image: 15565160 * 512 / 1024^3]

It's important to note that `du` assumes the block size is equal to (in order), the value set by the `--block-size=` flag, the value of the `DU_BLOCK_SIZE`, `BLOCK_SIZE`, or `BLOCKSIZE` environment variables, or `1024`. 1024 bytes is the common default block size used by most modern file systems. But 512 byte blocks is not particularly rare. Check these variables, one of them is probably set to 512. Or you may have a particularly old version of `du`.

Comment: This explains it! Thanks so much. Had no idea that du defaulted to block size. Assumed that the bytes from ls were consistent, but clearly a bad assumption